Unreal Engine not taking any function key inputs
Unreal Engine utilizes f (function) keys. On a textfield on the config window e.g. "Editor Preferences -> General -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Possess or Eject Player" I see f8 is assigned by default but when I type in any key the textfield fills in with the name of the key I type in (e.g. if I type in backspace, the filed shows so). But I don't see any f keys show up on that textfield. Am I missing anything?
I DO see F keys e.g. f1 DOES mute operating system's audio output, so the OS is taking in f-key inputs, but for the same f1 key, the aforementioned config window on Unreal Engine doesn't show its name when the key is pressed.

Unreal Engine 5.5 (compiled locally from source)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Device: Thinkpad p16s


UPDATE-1. The original observation was done on an external USB keyboard. Now, on the laptop's dedicated keyboard:

on the config window I DO see the input from the function keys (e.g. F7, F8) are recognized, but with Fn key pressed together.
But on Play Mode, F8 (pressed with Fn) that is supposed to trigger "eject" does NOT trigger it.


If the problem is just related to F8 and not all of the function keys, then it might be worth reading https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/f8-possess-or-eject-player-hotkey-not-ejecting-my-player/476655/7
As the very least it describes where some of the eject functionality is implemented in the code, so you can debug it.

I don’t know if this is a bug or intended behavior,
but if you look at the C++, in DebuggerCommands.cpp, in FInternalPlayWorldCommandCallbacks::PlayInEditorFloating_Clicked(),
you can see the code is getting ActiveLevelViewport, but it is not
setting SessionParams.DestinationSlateViewport before calling
GUnrealEd->RequestPlaySession(SessionParams), which other similar
functions do.
In that same file, in
FInternalPlayWorldCommandCallbacks::CanPossessEjectPlayer(), it checks
DestinationSlateViewport.IsValid()
If you stop in the debugger, you’ll see that DestinationSlateViewport
is null, so that function will return false, which prevents the user
from Ejecting during Play In New Editor Window.

